# nodejs not receiving request on forwarded port

Tags: node.js, dns

I am trying to get my router to forward requests made to my noip dynamic dns to my local computer where I have a nodjs running, waiting for requests on port 14555.

I have the noip dns set up so that a netcat running locally does receive any calls made to port 14555 (i.e. with a browser):

```
ncat -l -n -v -v -k -p 14555
Ncat: Version 5.59BETA1 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:14555
Ncat: Connection from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56409.
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1430939580269-4 HTTP/1.1
Host: someDomain.ddns.net:14555
Connection: keep-alive
...
NCAT DEBUG: Closing connection.
Ncat: Connection from 84.167.116.141:56411.
```

However although the call seems to pass everything and arrives at my machine, node doesn't listen to it. It does not receive anything:

```
HTTP server listening at 0.0.0.0:14555/
```

My receiving server is configured like this:

```
var self = this;
// Start the server
this.httpServer = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
    // Send HTML headers and message
    res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
    res.end('<h1>Hello Socket Lover!</h1>');
});

//Listen on the port for HTTP requests
this.httpServer.listen(cfg.port, '0.0.0.0');

console.log('HTTP server listening at 0.0.0.0:' + cfg.port + '/');
```

P.S.: This questions was originally asked on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/690115/nodejs-not-receiving-request-on-forwarded-port), but I was asked to move it here.

*edit 1: I did another experiment with an nginx listening on port 80 and forwarding port 80, which had the same result: call arrives on port 80 on local computer but nginx does not receive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution eventually. It was a problem caused by my router.

See [my post on super user](https://superuser.com/questions/911803/nodejs-not-receiving-request-on-forwarded-port/911857#911857) for the answer.